# Optimize query Teradata

Tags: optimization, teradata, join

I would appreciate it if you can help me with a problem that i have.
I have this join condition :

```
SELECT *
FROM    
T1_STAGING.(first_table) AS STG 
JOIN T1_STAGING.(second_table) AS B
    ON 
    (
            STG.DLOF_ID_NO=B.DLOF_ID_NO_RU
    )
```

This simple join is taking too long to finish, more than 20 minutes. The data of each table is less than 600,000K data. i tried the following things :

I took statistics on each table. 
I changed the columns to be PRIMARY INDEX. 
I created JOIN INDEX for the second table but still nothing! 
The query never ends it takes 20 mins ++. This seems to be data distribution problem in the second table, but i can't do anything with the data. 
Please bear in mind that if i join my first_table with any other it takes only seconds.

Can you give me a suggestion to try? I need to optimize it for better performance.

Here is the explain of TERADATA:
Explain SEL *
FROM
    T1_STAGING.DLS_DLO_OWS_STAGE_STG AS STG 
    JOIN T1_STAGING.DLS_ACQUISITION_STG AS B
        ON 
        (
                STG.DLOF_ID_NO=B.DLOF_ID_NO_RU
        )

1) First, we lock a distinct T1_STAGING."pseudo table" for read on a
     RowHash to prevent global deadlock for T1_STAGING.STG.
  2) Next, we lock a distinct T1_STAGING."pseudo table" for read on a
     RowHash to prevent global deadlock for T1_STAGING.B.
  3) We lock T1_STAGING.STG for read, and we lock T1_STAGING.B for read.
  4) We execute the following steps in parallel.
       1) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from T1_STAGING.B by way of
          an all-rows scan with no residual conditions split into Spool
          2 (all_amps) with a condition of ("DLOF_ID_NO_RU IN (:*)") to
          qualify skewed rows and Spool 3 (all_amps) with a condition
          of ("DLOF_ID_NO_RU IN (:*)") to qualify rows matching skewed
          rows of the skewed relation and Spool 4 (all_amps) with
          remaining rows fanned out into 2 hash join partitions.  Spool
          2 is built locally on the AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order
          Spool 2 by row hash.  The size of Spool 2 is estimated with
          high confidence to be 303 rows.  Spool 3 is built locally on
          the AMPs.  The size of Spool 3 is estimated with high
          confidence to be 4,710 rows.  Spool 4 is redistributed by
          hash code to all AMPs.  The size of Spool 4 is estimated with
          high confidence to be 97,742 rows.  The estimated time for
          this step is 1.27 seconds.
       2) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from T1_STAGING.STG by way of
          an all-rows scan with no residual conditions split into Spool
          6 (all_amps) with a condition of ("DLOF_ID_NO IN (:*)") to
          qualify skewed rows and Spool 5 (all_amps) with a condition
          of ("DLOF_ID_NO IN (:*)") to qualify rows matching skewed
          rows of the skewed relation and Spool 7 (all_amps) with
          remaining rows fanned out into 2 hash join partitions.  Spool
          6 is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 6 is
          estimated with high confidence to be 21,587 rows.  Spool 5 is
          built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 5 is estimated
          with high confidence to be 7 rows.  Spool 7 is redistributed
          by hash code to all AMPs.  The size of Spool 7 is estimated
          with high confidence to be 301,682 rows.  The estimated time
          for this step is 4.20 seconds.
  5) We execute the following steps in parallel.
       1) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 5 (Last Use) by
          way of an all-rows scan into Spool 8 (all_amps), which is
          duplicated on all AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 8
          by the hash code of (T1_STAGING.STG.DLOF_ID_NO).  The size of
          Spool 8 is estimated with high confidence to be 336 rows (
          640,080 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.01
          seconds.
       2) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 3 (Last Use) by
          way of an all-rows scan into Spool 9 (all_amps), which is
          duplicated on all AMPs.  The result spool file will not be
          cached in memory.  The size of Spool 9 is estimated with high
          confidence to be 226,080 rows (391,796,640 bytes).  The
          estimated time for this step is 1.05 seconds.
  6) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 8 (Last Use) by way of a
     RowHash match scan, which is joined to Spool 2 (Last Use) by way
     of a RowHash match scan.  Spool 8 and Spool 2 are joined using a
     merge join, with a join condition of ("DLOF_ID_NO = DLOF_ID_NO_RU").
     The result goes into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built locally
     on the AMPs.  The result spool file will not be cached in memory.
     The size of Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be 2,121
     rows (11,491,578 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.03
     seconds.
  7) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 6 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 9 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan.  Spool 6 and Spool 9 are joined using a single
     partition hash join, with a join condition of ("DLOF_ID_NO =
     DLOF_ID_NO_RU").  The result goes into Spool 1 (group_amps), which
     is built locally on the AMPs.  The result spool file will not be
     cached in memory.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with low
     confidence to be 9,243,161 rows (50,079,446,298 bytes).  The
     estimated time for this step is 0.60 seconds.
  8) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 4 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 7 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan.  Spool 4 and Spool 7 are joined using a hash join
     of 2 partitions, with a join condition of ("DLOF_ID_NO =
     DLOF_ID_NO_RU").  The result goes into Spool 1 (group_amps), which
     is built locally on the AMPs.  The result spool file will not be
     cached in memory.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with low
     confidence to be 731,525 rows (3,963,402,450 bytes).  The
     estimated time for this step is 0.96 seconds.
  9) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
     statement 1.  The total estimated time is 6.84 seconds.

Comment: Is this a n-1 join, i.e. is there a Primary Key on one of the columns? Otherwise you might simply create a huge result... Can you show the Explain?

Comment: the result is not huge is around 400,000 data. I don't have any primary index in any table. As i said i recreate the tables with PRIMARY INDEX but nothing happened.

Comment: Can you show the Explain and add some more details like statistics of the join columns?

Comment: You get a "Partial Redistribution/Partial Duplication" Join optimization, so you're running TD14.10. Partition Joins are quite sensitive for wrong estimates, can you check if statistics are up to date?

Comment: hello sorry for the late answer. Yes my statistics are up to date!

Answer (score 0):

600,000K you mean 600M, right? ;) That's not that little.

First. The columns used in JOIN should be indexed. (Looks like you've done it)
2. Add WHERE condition to choose specific values you need
3. Add LIMIT to limit the SELECT result

And finally, use EXPLAIN SELECT ... to understand the issue.

Comment: 600 thousands of data. As i said when i join a different table with more data like 9 millions it runs in seconds. I can not add a limit . I want all the data that comply to this join condition. I don't want to limit my data. We are talking about teradata here which is used for DATA WAREHOUSING.